# Python Binary Tree print nodes with two exactly two children

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

How do I make a function that returns the number of nodes in a tree that have two children?

My class code is as follows:

```
class RefBinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.key = data
        self.left = left
        self.right  = right

    def insert_left(self, value):
        self.left = RefBinaryTree(value, left=self.left)  

    def insert_right(self, value):
        self.right = RefBinaryTree(value, right=self.right)

    def get_left_subtree(self):
        return self.left

    def get_right_subtree(self):
        return self.right

    def set_value(self, new_value):
        self.key = new_value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.key

    def create_string(self, indent):
        string = str(self.key) + '---+'
        if self.left:
            string += '\n(l)' + indent + self.left.create_string(indent + '    ')
        if self.right:
            string += '\n(r)' + indent + self.right.create_string(indent + '    ')
        return string

    def __str__(self):
        return self.create_string('  ')
```

I'm guessing it would be best to use recursion. Any hints or helpful links would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Just use recursion, where do you get stuck?

Comment: look for some tree traversal algorithms. The recursive ones are very simple.

Answer (score 2):

It's really quite simple to count two-child nodes recursively. If you return a number with each function call (zero as the base case) you can simply add 1 every time you find a two-child node:

```
def findDoubleNodes(tree):
    if tree == None or (tree.left == None and tree.right == None):
        # base case
        return 0
    elif tree.left <> None and tree.right <> None:
        # both have children, so add one to our total and go down one level
        return findDoubleNodes(tree.left)+findDoubleNodes(tree.right) + 1
    else:
        # only one child, so only go down one level
        return findDoubleNodes(tree.left)+findDoubleNodes(tree.right)
```

Inputting a `RefBinaryTree` returns the number of nodes with two children.  An example:

```
x = RefBinaryTree(1)
x.insert_left(5)
x.left.insert_left(6)
x.left.insert_right(7)
x.left.right.insert_left(8)
x.left.right.insert_right(9)
x.left.right.right.insert_right(10)
```

The (lazily) created tree looks like this:

```
    1
   /
  5
 / \
6   7
   / \
  8   9
       \
       10
```

And `findDoubleNodes(x)` returns `2`, as only two nodes (5 and 7) have two children.

Additionally, adding a left child to node 9 (`x.left.right.right.insert_left(11)`) has the expected result, returning `3`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
def countNodes(tree):
    if tree is None:
        return 0
    left = tree.get_left_subtree()
    rght = tree.get_right_subtree()
    return (0 if left is None or rght is None else 1) \
           + countNodes(left) + countNodes(rght)
```